# What to do with ignore different files for 3 different push destinations?

Tags: git

In my local computer, I have a git repository and working directory where I edit my programs and run some tests on the programs.

In github, I also have a git repository of my local one, except that a directory called `data` in my local is not shown there. I did that by adding `data/` to `.gitignore` file under my local working directory.

Now, I would like to run my programs on a server. I want to have all the files in my local working directory be on the server, instead of ignoring `data/`. What shall I do to make that happen on the server, while still ignoring `data/` on github?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gitignore` only ignores *untracked* files. If you want `data/` on the server, you need to either add it to the repository, or copy it to the server manually.

You might want to maintain two branches in parallel, one with `data/` that you checkout on the server and one without `data/` that you checkout on your local host.

Comment: thanks. WHat do you mean tracked and untracked files?

Comment: An untracked file is one that is present in the working directory, but not part of the repository. When you run `git status`, it will show a list of all untracked files; one purpose of `.gitignore` is to tell `git` which untracked files it should not report. Technically, *all* directories are untracked, but you can think of an untracked directory as one which does not contain any tracked files (i.e., files that are in the repository).